# OAuth2: Resource Owner OpenID Grant?

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization, openid

I've been struggling over the past couple of days to wrap my head around something. I have worked with OAuth2 servers before and am familiar with all the spec grant types. But I'm working on an application where I want to use an OpenID service for user authentication to my OAuth2 server.

But the issue is I want an implicit trust with my application and my server, so somewhat like the resource owner password grant. But the issue is im not authenticating with a password I'm authenticating with OpenID provider.

So would I be stuck basically making a custom grant type to deal with this? Is there any future plans to implement such grant type in the spec? Any advice would be really appreciated as I cannot find any relevant information after searching long and hard.

Thanks

Comment: Have checked OpenId Connect? It nicely integrates OpenId with OAuth2, but maybe you need something else here.

Comment: I have looked at OpenID Connect and it would be useful if I wanted to be the OpenID provider but I want to authenticate using a 3rd party provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spec has drafted the OAuth assertion flow that is basically meant for authenticating with external providers. The IETF draft can be located [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-assertions-01)

OAuth Server's that support the assertion flow are (not a complete list):

1. [songkick/oauth2-provider](https://github.com/songkick/oauth2-provider) (Ruby)
2. [RangelReale/osin](https://github.com/RangelReale/osin) (Golang)